# Change sort icon in Bootstrap Table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

It is possible to change sort icon [to this](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html):
 [image]

In the new demo and from default the Bootstrap Table comes with ugly non-retina icons:

http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to custom your css style, for example like this:

```
.fixed-table-container thead th .both {
    background-image: none;
}

.fixed-table-container thead th .asc {
    background-image: url(asc.png);
}

.fixed-table-container thead th .desc {
    background-image: url(desc.png);
}
```

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/3258/